# How do I use the var.split

Tags: python, split

```
if inp.startswith("add "):
    print(((inp.split('d ')[1]).split(', ')[0]) + ((inp.split(' ')[1]).split(', ')[1]))
```

I am getting the error message that the list index is out of range
what do i do

code to replicate the error:

```
inp = "add 12, 12"
if inp.startswith("add "):
   print(((inp.split('d ')[1]).split(', ')[0]) + ((inp.split(' ')[1]).split(', ')[1]))
```

Comment: We cannot replicate this issue without knowing what string you are using.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Kindly consider adding a short code that reproduces the said error. It will help others understand the problem better and provide you useful solution.

Comment: What output do you expect with that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.split(', ')[1]
```

you are resting here on the fact that `split` gives you (at least) two elements. Suppose that your input string does not contain a `,`, then you are trying to fetch the second entry from a list that contains only one element --> index out of range error.

Globally your use of `split` is ok, but you need to make sure that such errors won't happen by adding checks or handling errors.

### edit

with your example:

```
> inp.split(' ')[1]
'12,'
```

on this part you run

```
.split(', ')
```

however since ', ' is not present in '12,', this string is not split, so you cannot take the second element.

Answer (score 0):

if the string is 'add ', you'll have index out of range error in the last split:

```
In [74]: inp
Out[74]: 'add '

In [75]: (inp.split(' ')[1])
Out[75]: ''

In [76]: (inp.split(' ')[1]).split(', ')[1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-2cd8aab4e893> in <module>
----> 1 (inp.split(' ')[1]).split(', ')[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```